# TestCafe Screenshot gives error Error: not opened at WebSocket.send

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I get the following error

```
Was unable to take a screenshot due to an error.

  Error: not opened
      at WebSocket.send (/userdir/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:359:18)
      at Chrome.enqueueCommand (/userdir/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/chrome.js:130:16)
      at /userdir/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/chrome.js:88:28
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Chrome.send (/userdir/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/chrome.js:87:16)
      at Object.handler [as captureScreenshot] (/userdir/node_modules/chrome-remote-interface/lib/api.js:32:23)
      at Object.getScreenshotData (/userdir/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/provider/built-in/dedicated/chrome/cdp.ts:129:46)
      at BrowserProviderPluginHost.takeScreenshot (/userdir/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/provider/built-in/dedicated/base.js:68:52)
      at BrowserProvider.takeScreenshot (/userdir/node_modules/testcafe/src/browser/provider/index.ts:354:31)
```

It works for the first two times and later it keeps giving the above error.

My code is

```js
await t.takeScreenshot()
```

Video recording also gives the below error consistently. I have tried in many ways but was never able to get the video recording started.

```
 An unexpected error has occured:  { Error: Unable to set video or encoding options when video recording is disabled. Specify the base path where video files are stored to enable recording.
```

I did try providing the base path

```
        .video('artifacts/videos/', {
            singleFile: true,
            failedOnly: false,
            pathPattern: '${TEST_INDEX}/${USERAGENT}/${FILE_INDEX}.mp4',
            ffmpegPath: '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'
        }, {
            r: 20,
            aspect: '4:3'
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is not related directly to TestCafe. TestCafe is using the Chrome DevTools protocol internally, and the error occurs inside protocol methods. The cause of the issue is unclear, but I found some recommendations in the https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/623 issue. Please check that thread. Also, install the latest TestCafe and nodejs versions. If nothing helps resolve the issue, please create a reproducible project to demonstrate the issue and share it at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md.
Please also specify:

- your TestCafe version;
- your nodejs version;
- whether you are using a docker and whether you can reproduce the issue without it;
- how much RAM you have on your machine or VM;
- the command that you use to run testcafe (i.e `testcafe chrome test.js`).